# Как создать аналог event listener на php?

Tags: php, ооп, методы

Нужен метод который будет отслеживать изменения в свойствах другого класса. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать или где об этом почитать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Данный паттерн носит название **Observer**. Описывать тут нет смысла - идите в источники.

[Сюда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

[и сюда](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.splobserver.php)

[и ещё сюда](https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/Behavioral/Observer/README.html)

[да и вообще](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=php%20Observer&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)